# nginx - redirect a domain to another domain but a subdirectory to an html file

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

How could I redirect the `domain1.com` to `domain2.com`, but `domain1.com/subdir` to a directory which contains `index.html` file?

I've tried different configs but none of them worked, like:

```
location /
{
    return 301 http://domain2.com;
}

location /subdir
{
    autoindex on;
    root /home/www;
}
```

Comment: It looks like this config should make what you want. May be you should use `alias` instead of `root` for subdir location. Everything else looks fine for me.

Comment: Unfortunately it gives error `404 Not Found` for `http://domain1.com/subdir` even though the index.html file exists there. It gives the same result when I use `alias` instead of `root`.